# visual studio asking to browse to file in added package library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, twilio

I added the Twilio package to my project via nuget. The package downloaded all its required dependencies. I create a simple sub to send a sample sms message for testing.(And yes, I have confirmed that the accountSid and authToken variables have the right values.)

When stepping through this sub to find out why it doesnt work, on the line Dim client = New TwilioRestClient......

Visual Studio dumps me to a file dowload dialog looking for a Core.cs file. This is a VB.Net web application project but I would assume that the package works for all of .Net languages but maybe I'm wrong?

All the required Twilio dll's are referenced in the project. Any help appreciated.

```
 Public Shared Sub SendAuthCodeViaSms(ByVal number As String)
        Dim twilioAccountInfo As Dictionary(Of String, String) = XmlParse.GetAccountInfoFromXmlFile("twilio")
        Dim accountSid As String = twilioAccountInfo("username")
        Dim authToken As String = twilioAccountInfo("password")
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountSid) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken)) Then
            Dim client = New TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken)
            client.SendMessage(TwilioSendNumber, number, "Testing twilio text message send functionality")
        Else
            'log error and alert developer
        End If

    End Sub
```

**Addtl Info**

Error messages when cancelling the file search dialog;

`Locating source for 'C:\Users\demo\Documents\GitHub\twilio-    csharp\src\Twilio.Api\Core.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {64 ba 18 a6 c7 3e 56 93 be d5 41 d3 9d 5f 12 20}
The file 'C:\Users\demo\Documents\GitHub\twilio-csharp\src\Twilio.Api\Core.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'C:\Users\demo\Documents\GitHub\twilio-csharp\src\Twilio.Api\Core.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'C:\Users\demo\Documents\GitHub\twilio-csharp\src\Twilio.Api\Core.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\vccorlib\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include'...
Looking in directory 'F:\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: C:\Users\demo\Documents\GitHub\twilio-csharp\src\Twilio.Api\Core.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'C:\Users\demo\Documents\GitHub\twilio-csharp\src\Twilio.Api\Core.cs'.`

Why would the files be on the machine when nuget installed the dll's into my project? You cant debug into a dll.

Comment: That dialog is to debug into their source.  You can click Cancel and still see the exception.

Comment: see the post update, you cant debug into a dll

Comment: Wrong.  You can debug into a DLL, as long as you have symbols (which are downloaded from SymbolSource via NuGet) and source (which you can download yourself from GitHub)

Comment: The problem appears to be that twilio doesnt work with vb.net on c#

Comment: Wrong; any normal .Net assembly will work with any CLI-compliant language.  You're getting this message because it's trying to debug into source code that you don't have.